# Group objects based on timestamp

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to wrap my head around this task in JavaScript. I've a list of objects with timestamps:

```
{ "timestamp": 2019-04-24 07:04:32.820, "data": 0.54 } 
{ "timestamp": 2019-04-24 08:06:22.820, "data": 0.34 } 
{ "timestamp": 2019-04-24 08:41:42.720, "data": 0.89 } 
{ "timestamp": 2019-04-24 09:11:32.430, "data": 0.14 } 
{ "timestamp": 2019-04-24 09:21:31.213, "data": 0.63 }
{ "timestamp": 2019-04-24 10:06:11.120, "data": 0.85 }
```

I want to get the objects grouped hourly based on a given start time. 
So if the start is 2019-04-24 06:44:00, the first period is from 6:44 - 7:44, then 7:44 - 8:44, 8:44 - 9:44 and 9:44 - 10:44 and so forth. For the input I imagine the following output:

```
[ { "1": [{ "timestamp": 2019-04-24 07:04:32.820, "data": 0.54 }] }, 
  { "2": [{ "timestamp": 2019-04-24 08:06:22.820, "data": 0.34 }, 
       { "timestamp": 2019-04-24 08:41:42.720, "data": 0.89 }] },
  { "3": [{ "timestamp": 2019-04-24 09:11:32.430, "data": 0.14 }, 
       { "timestamp": 2019-04-24 09:21:31.213, "data": 0.63 }] },
  { "4": [{ "timestamp": 2019-04-24 10:06:11.120, "data": 0.85 }]
```

I'm pretty lost how to grasp this, any ideas?

Comment: Did the answer from Yann solve your issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give you an integer representing a number of milliseconds (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime):

```
new Date('2019-04-24 07:04:32.820').getTime();
```

One you have this, grouping your timestamps is pretty straightforward.
You can do something like this (note that the output is formatted a bit differently but you get the idea):

```
let inputs = [
{ "timestamp": '2019-04-24 07:04:32.820', "data": 0.54 } ,
{ "timestamp": '2019-04-24 08:06:22.820', "data": 0.34 } ,
{ "timestamp": '2019-04-24 08:41:42.720', "data": 0.89 } ,
{ "timestamp": '2019-04-24 09:11:32.430', "data": 0.14 } ,
{ "timestamp": '2019-04-24 09:21:31.213', "data": 0.63 } ,
{ "timestamp": '2019-04-24 10:06:11.120', "data": 0.85 }]

const MS_PER_HOURS = 3600 * 1000;
let startTime = new Date(inputs[0].timestamp).getTime();
let outputs = [];
inputs.forEach(input=>{
  let time = new Date(input.timestamp).getTime();
  let hour = Math.floor((time-startTime) / MS_PER_HOURS);
  if(!outputs[hour]) outputs[hour] = [];
  outputs[hour].push(input);
});

console.log(outputs);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following for you...
I think you may like it. please let me know my friend...

```js
var AllTimes = [
    new Date("2019-04-24 09:12:32.430"),
    new Date("2019-04-24 09:33:29.213"),

    new Date("2019-04-24 07:04:32.820"),
    new Date("2019-04-24 08:54:42.720"),

    new Date("2019-04-24 08:06:22.820"),
    new Date("2019-04-24 07:038:11.110"),

    new Date("2019-04-24 07:038:11.110")
];



function renderTimes(unorderedTimes)
{

    var NewTimeEntry = class 
    {
        constructor(startTime, endTime)
        {     
            this.startTime = new Date(startTime);
            this.endTime = new Date(endTime);
        }
    }

    function DateValidationFunction(DateTime)
    {
        return typeof DateTime !== undefined && DateTime !== null && typeof DateTime === "object";
    }




    //Taking a deep copy and then sorting...
    var orderedTimes = unorderedTimes.slice().sort();
    var orderedTimesCount = orderedTimes.length;
    var Pairings = [];

    var GroupNumber = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < (orderedTimesCount); i=i+2)
    {
        var startTime = orderedTimes[i],
            endTime = orderedTimes[i+1],
            test1 = DateValidationFunction(startTime),
            test2 = DateValidationFunction(endTime);

        if(test1 && test2)
        {
            Pairings.push(new NewTimeEntry(startTime, endTime));
        }
    }

    return Pairings;

}

var Answer = {
    Times: renderTimes(AllTimes),
    Count: renderTimes(AllTimes).length
};

//Displays the Answer...
console.log({Answer})
```

Comment: Question Do you know if the times that you have access to are one Hour Apart? Or is that someThing you want me to determine? also what do you want the program to do if there are two items that are from withIn the hour Mark? Should it Aggragate to the Collection of that Time Interval? Last Question...Do you abolutelly need the data formated in the Collection of Collections? Or Do is my JSON interpretation ok with you?

Comment: I've specified my post a bit more.

Comment: @UncleFifi you could update your previous answer. no need to post multiple answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for???
Partitioned by the Hour like to posted...

```js
var AllTimes = [
    new Date("2019-04-24 09:12:32.430"),
    new Date("2019-04-24 09:33:29.213"),

    new Date("2019-04-24 07:04:32.820"),
    new Date("2019-04-24 08:54:42.720"),

    new Date("2019-04-24 08:06:22.820"),
    new Date("2019-04-24 07:038:11.110"),

    new Date("2019-04-24 07:038:11.110")
];



function renderTimes(unorderedTimes)
{
    // Class responsible for keeping track of times in partition...
    var timeManager = class 
    {
        constructor()
        {     
            this.timePartition = {};
        }

        addTime(newTime)
        {
            var Hour = newTime.getHours();
            if(this.timePartition[`Hour_${Hour}`] !== undefined)
            {
                //This Object is defined...
                this.timePartition[`Hour_${Hour}`].push(newTime);

            } else {
                //This Object is NOT defined...
                this.timePartition[`Hour_${Hour}`] = [newTime];
            }
        }
    }


    //Taking a deep copy and then sorting...
    var orderedTimes = unorderedTimes.slice().sort();
    var orderedTimesCount = orderedTimes.length;
    var _timeManager = new timeManager();

    for(var i = 0; i < orderedTimesCount; i++)
    {
        var timeInstance = orderedTimes[i];
        _timeManager.addTime(timeInstance);
    }

    return _timeManager.timePartition;

}

var Answer = {
    Times: renderTimes(AllTimes),
    Count: renderTimes(AllTimes).length
};

//Displays the Answer...
console.log({Answer})
```

Comment: I think you're missing the point, I'm interested in hours, but from a starting time.

Comment: Yes I believe I am missing the point, but I have tried my best with the instructions I received. I can keep helping you if youd like but I would need more specific instructions.